# How to output all XML element attributes using a foreach loop?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

New to XML here.

Consider this simple XML schema:

```
<products>
    <category name="furniture">
                <item name="chair" name2="table">
                            <size>
                                <small>10</small>
                                <large>20</large>
                            </size>
                </item>
                <item name="cabinet">
                            <size>
                                <small>15</small>
                                <large>30</large>
                            </size>
                </item>
                <item name="shelf" name2="box" name3="frame">
                            <size>
                                <small>5</small>
                                <large>10</large>
                            </size>
                </item>
    </category>
</products>
```

Notice each `<item>` element has a different amount of attributes.

I've been trying to echo out the attributes using XPATH and a foreach loop without success.
Surely I'm missing a small piece of syntax.

```
$dom=simplexml_load_file("file.xml");

foreach ($dom->xpath("/products/category[@name='furniture']/item") as $parse)     
    echo'<tr><td>'.$parse->attributes().'</td></tr>';
```

$parse->attributes(); only gives me the first attribute of the element.
Output looks like this:

```
<tr><td>chair</td></tr>
<tr><td>cabinet</td></tr>
<tr><td>shelf</td></tr>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks Amal, a nested foreach would work but this XML is only a small segment of a much larger XML file. I wouldn't want to inflict the loop on the rest of the file. I'm looking for something along the lines of var_dump if that makes sense...

Comment: Okay, what's the expected output?

Comment: all the attributes, one after the other (or per line - it doesn't matter), so for example: `chair table cabinet shelf box frame`. That's basically all the attributes in every `<item>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($dom->xpath("/products/category[@name='furniture']/item") as $parse) {
    foreach ($parse->attributes() as $attr) {
        echo '<tr><td>'. $attr . '</td></tr>'."\n";   
    }
}
```